# How to interpret the sample_weight parameter in MiniBatchKMeans?

Tags: scikit-learn, clustering, text-mining, k-means, weighted-data

I am using scikit-learn [MiniBatchKMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html) to do text clustering.

In the [fit()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.fit) function there is a parameter `sample_weight` described as follows:

> The weights for each observation in X. If None, all observations are
> assigned equal weight (default: None).

How should I interpret it exactly?

For instance, if I assigned greater weight to certain observations, will the centroid be nearer to that observations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, *the parameter is available in the vanilla K-Means too.*

> *The algorithm supports sample weights, which can be given by a parameter sample_weight. This allows assigning more weight to some samples when computing cluster centers and values of inertia. For example, assigning a weight of 2 to a sample is equivalent to adding a duplicate of that sample to the dataset X.*

[*scikit-learn.org*](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#k-means)